# Can I assume NSObject as a kind of CFType in Cocoa-touch?

Tags: cocoa-touch, nsobject

I'm guessing `NSObject` is a kind of a `CFType`, but I have no sure. There is no mention about this in documentation. Can I assume it toll-free bridged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not toll-free bridged.
[Here is the Apple Documentation on Toll Free Bridged types.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFDesignConcepts/Articles/tollFreeBridgedTypes.html)  NSObject is not listed.